# Multi select dropdown showing additional dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am creating a multi-select dropdown using bootstrap this is the html :

```
<form id="multiselectForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Browser</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <select class="form-control" name="browsers" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="chrome">Google Chrome</option>
        <option value="firefox">Firefox</option>
        <option value="ie">IE</option>
        <option value="safari">Safari</option>
        <option value="opera">Opera</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is the JS:

```
$('#multiselectForm').find('[name="browsers"]')
  .multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    // Re-validate the multiselect field when it is changed
    onChange: function(element, checked) {
      $('#multiselectForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'browsers');
      adjustByScrollHeight();
    },
    onDropdownShown: function(e) {
      adjustByScrollHeight();
    },
    onDropdownHidden: function(e) {
      adjustByHeight();
    }
  })
  .end();
```

But the required out is as follows:

[image]

I dont know why the box at the bottom with blue combo boxes appears, I want to remove that.

These the files I have included in my project, need to identify which one of them is interfering with multiselect dropdown :

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/bootstrap.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/select2.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/datepicker3.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/AdminLTE.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/skins/_all-skins.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/Afiniti.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/configtree.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/animate.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/d3-context-menu.css")
                .Include("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/font-awesome-anim.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/Less/bootstrap-multiselect.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/d3-context-menu.css"));
            //.Include("~/Content/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/jquery/jquery.tmpl.js")
            // .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/date/date.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/select2/select2.full.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/moment/moment.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/icheck/icheck.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/app.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/d3/d3.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/d3-context-menu.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/init.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/noty/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/noty/themes/default.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/noty/layout/center.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/noty/layout/topCenter.js")
            // FIXME: Adding this so the widgets may be initialized
            .Include("~/Scripts/Chart.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.sparkline.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/morris/morris.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/morris/raphael.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/gridmvc.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/bootstrap-multiselect-collapsible-groups.js")

            );
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/jquery")
            .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/Chart.js")
            );

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/logincss")
           .Include("~/Content/css/AdminLTE.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/Afiniti.css")
            );


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/loginjs")
          .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.js")
          .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.js")
          .Include("~/Content/js/plugins/icheck/icheck.js")
          .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
          .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
          .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));
```

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript for tags or token-input? Because at a glance and with only the bare code you've provided it looks like the 2nd option is a tokenized version of `[name=browsers]`

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin which reproduce this issue?

Comment: I have included the multiselect.js and Css files for this only and this code. @RobertC

Comment: I have attached the image of the output above, I just want dropdown not the boxes that appear below it. @MoshFeu

Comment: @NidaTariq - The code you've shown us cannot reproduce the display issue you're reporting. We need to know more of what JS is being included, perhaps what (if any) console errors are being logged.  David Stutz' Multiselect plugin doesn't do what you're showing (the second tag-style field) so my *assumption* is that some undisclosed JS is targeting the same select field.

Comment: I assume the same, I am unable to find what JS is interfering with it although I even tried using the  David Stutz' Multiselect plugin but it gives me the same result. @RobertC

Comment: So... can you show us more of the code? Because like I said above; without *more* to go on there isn't much we can do to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I am wondering which version of Bootstrap includes a 'multiselect' component ? Can you throw some light @NidaTariq

Comment: I am using bootstrap version v3.3.7 and I am using bootstrap multiselect from (https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) @rach8garg

Comment: I am using the following files in my project, I have edited them in the question. @RobertC

Comment: @NidaTariq - `multi-select` and `select2` both affect the `<select>` element.  Make sure that the Select2 plugin isn't targeting these dropdowns; it's what is likely creating the pillbox style appearance.

Comment: Thanks @RobertC . Issue is resolved. Select2 was interfering with multiselect.

Comment: how do I obtain a single value from multiselect dropdown on controller side? @RobertC

Comment: @coder_24 How did you resolve the interference?